# Includegraphics in a new page after the title page

Tags: graphics, positioning, titles

How to put a picture in a new page after the title page? I write it as follows, but it appears in the top and with a numbered page.

```
\begin{document}
\title{ }
 \author{me \\
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo.jpg}}
  \date{Thesis\\
  for \\
  September 2012}
  \newpage
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{basm.png}
  \end{center}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\title`, `\author` and `\date` macros just store their contents in auxiliary macros that is used upon execution of `\maketitle`. Moreover, `\maketitle` issues a page break if there is contents preceding it.

As such, I would assume the following would work for you:

```
% In preamble
\title{My thesis}
\author{me \\
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo.jpg}}
\date{Thesis\\
  for \\
  September 2012}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{basm.png}
\end{center}
\clearpage

% Other document content

\end{document}
```

You might also consider issuing `\pagenumbering{arabic}` as part of your "Other document content", to start numbering from page 1 again. However, without a complete MWE showing the structure, it's difficult to assess your use case.

---

The `titlepage` environment is also a possibility here. You could use, for example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\title{My thesis}
\author{Me, me and ME}
\date{\today \\[\bigskipamount] \includegraphics[width=2cm]{me}}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{basm}
\end{center}
\clearpage

Here is some more content.
\end{document} ​
```

Comment: Thanks, but it appears before the title page!

Comment: @Sara: According to your original requirement you wanted the image to appear *after* the title page. In my example I placed `\maketitle` *before* inserting the image `basm`, followed by a `\clearpage`. How can the image appear before the title?

Comment: yes thank you very much :), I understand now.